# iPhone 5s blur when closing app

Tags: iphone

I have an iPhone 5s. If I have apps open and try to close them (double press the home button, then swipe up), the desktop "blurs" before returning to its normal state. For example, I can see the carrier name moving and merging with the carrier name on the regular home screen. Is this normal behavior, and does anyone know how to fix this? I close apps all the time, so I find this a little annoying.

Comment: Normal behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "blur" would be considered "Normal" behavior!

The "blur" is used as an optical indication of application switching (and it is for your information).

The operating system would not need it, but the designers have decided to use it as information.

Changing that would require knowledge of operating system programing, and it is not recommended for general public users.